# how to pass function pointer as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, function, parameters

second line compiles well, but third gives me an errors

```
int (* const f)() = ff;
cout << typeid(replace<int (*)(), int, char>::type).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(replace<f, int, char>::type).name() << endl;

test.cpp:3:25: error: the value of ‘f’ is not usable in a constant expression 
test.cpp:1:15: note: ‘f’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
test.cpp:3:37: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A template argument can be a function pointer only if the parameter is a non-type parameter. But sadly C++11 does even not yet allow to use the full variety of constant expressions to compute a template argument. For a non-type pointer or reference, you are only allowed to pass the value of another template parameter or the directly obtained address of the function or object, without storing it first in a `const` / `constexpr` variable.

This limitation will most probably be lifted for next C++ revision.

Comment: @sehe please dont fix thing that fast. You deleted one paragraph i added :-)

Comment: Deleted my answer, this explains why the above fails - I was wrong.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Sorry! you can roll it back, not? (_You can't really say "I deleted it" - I didn't see a warning about concurrent editing. Which means, you must have missed the warning?_) Anyways, I'll let you fix it in order to avoid further mishaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use templated interface instead of function pointer:

```
template<class T>
class IMyInterface{
public:
 virtual void doSomething(const T& arg) =0;
};
```